# jQuery Throttle - Debounce | callback.apply is not a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, caroufredsel, typeerror, throttling

I'm using Ben Alman's jQuery throttle - debounce script and I keep on running into an Uncaught TypeError when it is triggered.

It should also be said that I am using Twitter Bootstrap as a framework for responsive design, AND have a few synchronized CarouFredSels on the page as well.

The error I'm getting is this:
Uncaught TypeError: callback.apply is not a function     jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js:149

I look at line 149 and this is the area of interest:

```
function wrapper() {
      var that = this,
        elapsed = +new Date() - last_exec,
        args = arguments;

      function exec() {
        last_exec = +new Date();
        callback.apply( that, args ); //LINE 149//
      };

      function clear() {
        timeout_id = undefined;
      };

      if ( debounce_mode && !timeout_id ) {
        exec();
      }

      timeout_id && clearTimeout( timeout_id );

      if ( debounce_mode === undefined && elapsed > delay ) {
        exec();

      } else if ( no_trailing !== true ) {
        timeout_id = setTimeout( debounce_mode ? clear : exec, debounce_mode === undefined ? delay - elapsed : delay );
      }
    };
```

I'm not really familiar with this script, since it was in place before I was asked to take over. The throttle script is triggered when the user clicks into a search field that toggles an "auto-complete" script to be implemented later on.

[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/Ly58gsuh/4/)

Comment: If you're going to add a fiddle, it needs to "work" (as in show your error) otherwise its pretty pointless.

Comment: jfiddle "works" now.

Comment: `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` - your fiddle does not even include the jquery version you're on.

Comment: umm... the result is displaying properly for me... is your browser cached?

Comment: No, you've forgotton to select the jquery version (click where it says "Javascript" and choose a jquery library from the dropdown)

Comment: Please click the JFIDDLE link within the question, I'm certain it is functioning properly with the error I am attempting to illustrate.

Comment: Just read the [documentation](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html#jQuery.debounce) ;) It's `$.debounce(delay, callback)` and not `$.debounce(callback, delay)`

Comment: @Andreas can you please put that in an answer. I had ZERO idea that the arguments were flipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to swap the parameters.
It's `$.debounce(delay, callback)` and not `$.debounce(callback, delay)`

---

**[jQuery.debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html#jQuery.debounce)**

Debounce execution of a function.  Debouncing, unlike throttling, guarantees that a function is only executed a single time, either at the very beginning of a series of calls, or at the very end.  If you want to simply rate-limit execution of a function, see the jQuery.throttle method.

**Usage**

```
var debounced = jQuery.debounce( delay, [ at_begin, ] callback );

jQuery('selector').bind( 'someevent', debounced );
jQuery('selector').unbind( 'someevent', debounced );
```

**Arguments**

`delay  (Number)`
A zero-or-greater delay in milliseconds.  For event callbacks, values around 100 or 250 (or even higher) are most useful.

`at_begin   (Boolean)`
Optional, defaults to `false`.  If at_begin is false or unspecified, callback will only be executed `delay` milliseconds after the last debounced-function call.  If `at_begin` is `true`, `callback` will be executed only at the first debounced-function call.  (After the throttled-function has not been called for `delay` milliseconds, the internal counter is reset)

`callback   (Function)`
A function to be executed after delay milliseconds.  The `this` context and all arguments are passed through, as-is, to `callback` when the debounced-function is executed.

Comment: thank you very much... I was looking at it so hard, that I didn't even notice the arguments were flipped.